# What does 数値化 mean?

Tags: kanji

It was part of 数値化します, and I have no idea what it means. The context deals with businesses, and I thought it's something like statistics, but the -shimasu threw me off, so I don't know anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

数値 value, numeric
化 change
So by adding する you create the verb "change to number" or "quantify"

化 is commonly used in this way when you want to state that something is changing to a certain shape or form. The generic word for change is 変化{へんか}. 石化 for example means "petrification" or "fossilization", directly translated to "turning to stone"